# Row MainAxisAlignment.start not work with SelectionArea feature in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I face the issue on the Flutter 3.7 version.  I found that Row MainAxisAlignment.start not work with SelectionArea feature in Flutter Web.  Please see the below code to show the text alignment incorrect position.  Please see the below screen with the extra space highlighted in yellow .

[image]

Here is the code.

```
Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: _event
                      .map((e) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 20,
                                  child: Text(
                                    _event.indexOf(e).toString(),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: SelectionArea(
                                    child: Text(
                                      e,
                                      softWrap: true,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              )
```

If I remove the SelectionArea Widget, it is resumed to normal alignment.

[image]

Do you know how to fix it to use SelectionArea and the text alignment show correct position?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by not to use SelectionArea but use SelectableRegion.  Finally, it can be selected and the text alignment is correct.

[image]

Here is my updated code.

```
SelectableRegion(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      selectionControls: materialTextSelectionControls,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: _event
                      .map((e) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 20,
                                  child: Text(
                                    (_event.indexOf(e) + 1).toString(),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Text(
                                    e,
                                    softWrap: true,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              )
```